# Disable button if order is canceled

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I added two button in order view it's working fine but i want to disable this button if order is complete and order is canceled time

My **Abstract** file

```
public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {

            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

            $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

           $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
            array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
        }


    }
```

Comment: order complete and order canceled?

Comment: yes @Qaisar....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code from

```
public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {

            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

            $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

           $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
            array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
        }


    }
```

TO

```
<?php

class Ar_Orderstatus_Model_Observer
{

    public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $order = $this->_initOrder();
            if (!$order->isCanceled() && $order->canShip()) {
                $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

                $block->addButton('rto', 
                    array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                        'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

               $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
        return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to send a mail to customer for current state

Comment: $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, ''); in your action file after$order->save()

Comment: If your are add new qus then i will added with code

Comment: ok i will post question

Comment: Can you please Check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93268/send-mail-to-change-state

Comment: Hi @Abdul How to disable Shipment button after click Shipment

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
      $order_id=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {

            $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');
          if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE  OR $order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
        {


          }else {
               $block->addButton('rto', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                    'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

          }

          if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE  OR $order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
        {


          }else {
             $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
            array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  

          }
             }


    }
```

Comment: It working but i want to hide that button

Comment: remove the if code  updated check it now

Comment: How to send a mail to customer for current state

Comment: you want send order update email or  custom email?