# Send mail to change state

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I added two button in order view it's working fine but i want to send email to that change state

My **Abstract** file

```
 <?php

class Ar_Orderstatus_Model_Observer
{

    public function addOrderstatusAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
            $order = $this->_initOrder();
            if (!$order->isCanceled() && $order->canShip()) {
                $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to Change Status?');

                $block->addButton('rto', 
                    array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('RTO'), 
                        'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/rto')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));

               $block->addButton('in_shipment', 
                array( 'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('In Shipement'), 
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment')}')", 'class' => 'go' ));  
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
        return $order;
    }
}
```

Controller file

```
<?php
class Ar_Orderstatus_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }


    public function rtoAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->setState('rto', true)
                    ->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, 'test');
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }

    }

    public function shipmentAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->setState('shipment', true)
                    ->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, 'test');
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Pls share your Controller code

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your controller file

```
<?php
class Ar_Orderstatus_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action 
{
    protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }


    public function rtoAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->setState('rto', true)
                    ->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, '');
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }

    }

    public function shipmentAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->setState('shipment', true)
                    ->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, '');
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No i didn't get any mail

Comment: check my update question

Comment: I tried my end it is working fine. Pls check your eamil or send email with valid email id

Comment: After change this controller file. If i click button it redirect to 404

Comment: In your Observer  replace $block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/in_shipment') to $block->getUrl('orderstatus/adminhtml_index/shipment')

Comment: action name is : shipmentAction in controller file

Comment: i added but i did n't get any mail

Answer (score 0):

try this code for sending the email..

```
public function rtoAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->setState('rto', true);
            $order->setStatus('rto');
            $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
            $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
            $order->save();
            $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, 'test');
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order state has not been changed.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }

}
```